# Check vectorization into a simple example with gcc-4.9

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

I am trying to check the vectorization into a simple loop. I am working on MacOS 19.5 and my code is compiled with `gcc-mp-4.9` (installed from Macports). For getting better performances with vectorization, I measure the elapsed time into a main loop and compared it with no-vectorization version.

Here's this simple code (that I compiled either with `"NOVEC"` or `"VEC" -D flag` ) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 1000000000

#ifdef NOVEC    
void addition_tab_novec(double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
#endif

#ifdef VEC    
void addition_tab_vec(double * restrict a, double * restrict b, double * restrict c) 
{
 int i;

 double *x = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
 double *y = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
 double *z = __builtin_assume_aligned(c, 16);

 for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Array index
  int i;

  // Two input arrays
  double *tab_x;
  double *tab_y;
  double *tab_z;

  // Time elapsed
  time_t time1, time2;

  // Allocation
  tab_x = (double*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
  tab_y = (double*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
  tab_z = (double*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));

  // Initialization
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
     {
      tab_x[i] = i;
      tab_y[i] = 2*i;
      tab_z[i] = 0.0;
     }

#ifdef NOVEC
     // Start time for vectorization
     time(&time1);

     // Addition function
     addition_tab_novec(tab_x, tab_y, tab_z);

     // Compute elapsed time for vectorization
     time(&time2);

     printf("No Vectorization - Time elapsed = %f seconds\n", difftime(time2, time1));
#endif

#ifdef VEC    
     // Start time for vectorization
     time(&time1);

     // Addition function
     addition_tab_vec(tab_x, tab_y, tab_z);

     // Compute elapsed time for vectorization
     time(&time2);

     printf("Vectorization - Time elapsed = %f seconds\n", difftime(time2, time1));
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

My issue is that I don't get better results with vectorization compared to no-vectorization version.

Given that I use "`__builtin_assume_aligned(array, 16)`", i.e a `16 bytes alignement`, I expect to get an elapsed time twice smaller into the measured loop (I use double arrays with `sizeof(double) = 8 bytes`)

But actually, I get 60 seconds without vectorization and 59s with it : how could I interpret these same results ?

Here are the compilation command line in two cases :

**No-Vectorization :**

```
gcc-mp-4.9 -DNOVEC -std=c99 -fno-tree-vectorize main_benchmark.c
```

**Vectorization :**

```
gcc-mp-4.9 -DVEC -std=c99 -Wa,-q -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec main_benchmark.c
```

I am not sure that optimization is not activated for no-vectorization compilation. If this is the case, how to disable it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Side note: In order to eliminate the possibility of caching heuristics (or any other runtime components on your platform, e.g., registers, memory state, etc.) impacting your measurements, I suggest that you repeat them with those two test cases in opposite order (i.e., `addition_tab_vec` then `addition_tab_novec`).

Comment: You should be able to see a bunch of vectorization optimization message while compiling with VEC flag, e.g. which lines are considered, and the optimization result. Also O0 should have non of those enabled.

Comment: Wei Shen: ok I saw this bunk of vectorization messages to notice all vectorized loops. With -O0, I get a runtime factor "1.5x" with the ratio of (no-vectorized)/(vectorized) runtimes. I get this result with a 1e+9 array size. Ideally, I thought that I would get a 2x factor for this ratio. So I would like to know which factors implies a smaller ratio (1.5x) than 2x (theoretical value due to 16 bytes alignement) ?

Comment: I am going also to generate assembly code for the 2 versions in order to see the differences that could implies a smaller speed up than the theoretical. Maybe I will need your help regarding this assembly code.

Comment: 1GiB is gigantic.  Even non-vectorized, it probably bottlenecks on DRAM bandwidth.  To see a difference, loop over the same 64kiB arrays many times.  (They will stay hot in L2 cache).  Also, it sounds like your non-vectorized version actually used `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` (which is correct), but that's not what the question says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, the `__builtin_assume_aligned` variant can be removed, as the vectorizer automatically aligns the data, with a special variant specialized for unaligned data. But you are right that explicit alignment and the restrict improves the code.

gcc-mp-6 -g -DVEC -std=c99 -Wa,-q -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 vec-sample.c -o vec-vec2

```
vec-sample.c:12:2: note: loop vectorized
vec-sample.c:12:2: note: loop versioned for vectorization because of possible aliasing
vec-sample.c:12:2: note: loop peeled for vectorization to enhance alignment
vec-sample.c:50:3: note: loop vectorized
vec-sample.c:50:3: note: loop peeled for vectorization to enhance alignment
vec-sample.c:12:2: note: loop vectorized
vec-sample.c:12:2: note: loop peeled for vectorization to enhance alignment
```

$ otool -tv vec-vec2

```
...
0000000100000920    vmovupd (%r10,%rax), %ymm0
0000000100000926    vaddpd  (%r14,%rax), %ymm0, %ymm0
000000010000092c    addl    $0x1, %ecx
000000010000092f    vmovupd %ymm0, (%r8,%rax)
...
```

Second, the addition code in the loop is vectorized (see `vaddpd` above), but the setup and malloc dominates the loop. There's not much left to measure the loop.

To measure the loop (osx only), I used

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#define SIZE 1000000
...
  // Time elapsed
  uint64_t t1, t2;
...
  // Start time for vectorization
  t1 = mach_absolute_time();

  // Addition function
  addition_tab_vec(tab_x, tab_y, tab_z);

  // Compute elapsed time for vectorization
  t2 = mach_absolute_time();

  printf("Vectorization - Time elapsed = %ld ticks\n", t2-t1);
```

which gives you a measurable 20% overhead with the SSE code, and 62% without SSE with -O0.

http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/ talks about the details a bit more.

Comment: rurban: thanks for your answer. You say that __builtin_assume_aligned variant can be removed and after, that explicit alignment and the restrict improves the code : so I have to remove it or not ?

Comment: you can remove it if you want smaller asm code. the code to check for alignment and restrict is automatically created.
I measured no time differences with or without.

btw: intel cpu's can vectorize on unaligned data just fine with the u opcode variant `vmovupd `, which is used here. So only restrict needs some check overhead if restricted or not, which is negligable with such strong loops.

Comment: rurban: ok and what about your values of overhead for with (20%) and without SSE (62%), how did you get these values from time elapsed into main loop (I mean how did you compute them from the time measured) ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see the assembler code.

Normally you could expect twice the performance at most, but in this case, given the size of the arrays, you're not going anywhere near that, the CPU is just sitting idle, waiting for the data, to be fetched into and flushed out of the caches, before it can do anything, and that's probably why there's no gain.

When dealing with lots of data there could also be memory management overhead involved, so it's best to lock the memory, see the `mlock` manpage.

Comment: IsmaelLuceno: Could you explain why there is a so large diffference between the runtimes got with 1e+8 array size (less than 1 second) and 1e+9 size (roughly 1 minute) : I would expect a 10 factor between the two sizes but in practice it is roughly a factor 100. Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell, you would have to measure that, but with 10x the size it could be a matter of memory management overhead. I'll edit my answer...